# SSAS Pivot with Two measure

Tags: excel, ssas, cube, measure

I have an SSAS Cube with two Fact tables, Actual and Budget. These are linked to three shared dimensions, Customer, Time & Cost Centre. The actual table is also linked to two further dimensions that have no relation to the budget measure.

When I create a pivot in Excel I can see budget by account for a particular month. If I drag in actual next to budget, the actual values come up, but the budget values go blank. I can't get the two to display side by side at the same time.

If I build the table using cube formulas there is no problem, although this loses the drill through action.

Can anyone advise what may be causing the issue?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: What's the granularity of your 'Actual' table compared to your 'Budget' table?

Comment: Thanks for this - I've managed to resolve. I think they were at a different granularity - month and date.